# IBM IoT Real-Time Insights Virtual Data Point?

Tags: real-time, ibm-cloud, iot

In IBM Real-Time Insights, I have a device for which I am creating a schema with a Virtual Data Point that derives its value from one of the device's data points (pressure divided by 100). However, when trying to visualize the data on a dashboard it shows up as "Not available". Is there anything in addition to the schema definition that I need to do in order for a Virtual Data Point to work?

Comment: Have you verified the device is connected?

Comment: Yes, the device is connected and I can see its data points, it is just the **virtual** data point that I have created that doesn't work or I don't know how to use. The easiest way forward is probably if someone could supply a working example of how to create virtual data points and use them in a dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual data points can currently only be used with rules. Dashboard widgets do not support displaying virtual data points.